# Class inside a class: 'is not a type' error

Tags: c++

Here is a simplified version of what I'm trying

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std ;

class a
    {
    public:
    a(int xinit, int yinit){x=xinit; y=yinit;}

    private:
    int x, y;
    };

class b
    {
    public:
    b(int pinit, int qinit){p=pinit; q=qinit;}

    private:
    int p,q;
    a Test(p,q);
    };

int main()
    {
    return 0;
    }
```

When compiling, it gives the errors 'p' is not a type. Could anyone tell me what's wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Most vexing parse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse). `a Test(p,q);` is parsed as a function declaration. You don't want that (I assume) - instead, you want to declare the member as `a Test;` and the assign it inside the constructor.

So what you can do is initializing it explicitly:

```
public:
b(int pinit, int qinit): p(pinit), q(qinit), Test(p, q) { }
```

Comment: Alternatively (in C++11 or later) initialise it in the declaration with braces: `a Test{p,q};`

Comment: Nice, never knew that you can define function inside a function.

Comment: @aisbaa: You can't. But you can declare a function inside a class.

Comment: @aisbaa You can't **define** a function inside a **function.** You can **declare** a member function inside a **class.**

Comment: @aisbaa By the way, your naming convention is overly confusing. I was almost lost debugging this damn initializer list before I realized that `a` is the type and `Test` is the name of the member variable. It should **really** be `A test;`...

Comment: Also note that the order of declaration is used to determine the order of initialization in the constructor initializer list. It you declare `A test;` before `p` and `q` it will go boom.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious (Yeah, and silly me, I've done that, god bless my foresight that I've compiled with `-Wall` thus clang++ could catch this me invoking nasal daemons...)

Comment: I am not familliar with this notation. What does the code between the : and the {} do? I thought everything b should do has to be inside the {}.

Comment: @RobVerheyen Google "C++ initializer list".

Answer (score 2):

By this line

```
a Test(p,q)
```

You [declare method](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/functions/) that returns type `a` and takes (anonymous) arguments of type `p` and `q`.
You probably wanted to use:

```
a Test(int p, int q);
```

If you want to declare it as class attribute, you have to create non parametric constructor for class a:

```
a() {}
```

And initialize `Test` in constructor either:

```
b(int pinit, int qinit)
{
    p=pinit;
    q=qinit;
    Test=a(p,q);
}
```

Or rather use [initializer syntax](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/101-constructor-initialization-lists/):

```
b(int pinit, int qinit):
    p(pinit),
    q(qinit),
    Test(pinit,qinit)
{
}
```

Comment: The nonsensical `Test=a(p,q)` is still present in the first ctor example.

Comment: This seems to work, but I don't understand why. Am I initializing an instance of my class a without arguments, and then changing it to an instance with arguments?

Answer (score 0):

You didn't declared data type for arguments of the function `Test`

```
a Test(p,q);
```

It must be like that:

```
a Test(int p, int q);
```

Answer (score 0):

You may write the code like this

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class a
{
public:
    a(int xinit, int yinit){x=xinit; y=yinit;}

private:
    int x, y;
};

class b
{
public:
    b(int pinit, int qinit):p(pinit), q(qinit), Test(p, q){}

private:
    int p,q;
    a Test;
};

int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```